# A simple project that uses the basic principles of OOP in Java

Tags: java, oop

I believe that we will never learn any programming language in depth until we apply all the theories on a real world application. And I kinda suck at the creativity thing. So I would want to ask for ideas on any simple application that the basic principles in OOP  (inheritance, interface, encapsulation, and polymorphism) can be best applied.

Answer (score 2):

Anything with a graphical user interface tends to utilise all the OOP principles pretty quickly.

- Event listeners implement some form of interface
- Components inherit from other components
- Data structures / models need to be encapsulated
- Different GUI components can be plugged in via polymorphism

As a project, what about implementing a custom Swing GUI component, for example a chess board?

If you find that too easy, then you can always write the AI so that it plays against you....

Comment: Thanks mikera. My initial plan was to create a chat system, but I have read stuff that Java is not good for this purpose. That would lead to my next question about when is Java good, and when it is not good for a particular application ?

Comment: @pneftali - Java would be absolutely fine for this. In fact I think it's a pretty good simple application to write as a learning project. The hardest bit would be the networking code, but I think there are some pretty good tutorials for this on the net.

Answer (score 0):

if you use netbeans, you found example project. Try to understand from the project. And then read name of attribute or method. And then image work of method like behavior work. I think this is simple ways to understand OOP in my ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try make a project that the user interact with a database. You will have to start making a module that handles the db part, a module that interacts with the user and something that correlates the two. For example an ordering system.